# What is the Excel hotkey to re-calculate all formula in sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, hotkeys

I have a sheet that contains many formulas. But they do not recalculate automatically when I change input.

I'm looking for a hotkey, that can re-calculate the sheet. According to [this page](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/shortx2k.htm), <kbd>F9</kbd> calculates all sheets in all open workbooks, and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> calculates the active sheet. Neither works for me. I know a tip: delete any row to refresh sheet. But my file is too long, and I'm not comfortable with this method.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

This often happens with very large and complex spreadsheets. Here are some workarounds you could try:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> to recheck all formula dependencies and then recalculate all formulas.
- Select any blank cell, press <kbd>F2</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Re-enter `=` :

  - Select cells that contain formulas you'd like to update
  - Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.
  - **Find what**: `=`
  - **Replace with**: `=`

  *This may take a while depending on the size of your workbook. Save your file before attempting.*

Comment: first time I've seen an emacs key chord on windows!!

Comment: I prefer the replace `=` by `=` ^^ So simple and stay the same for all version of the Office

Comment: I only have 3 usable fingers at the moment. What is the menu alternative to Ctrl+Alt+Shift+F9?

Comment: doesn't seem to be one but you can substitute AltGr for Ctrl+Alt , or use the onscreen keyboard to highlight multiple toggle keys

Comment: How to calc selection?

Answer (score 1):

From the settings, there is a part where you can ask excel to automatically update them once you have a new input. You don't need to press any hotkey...

Comment: OP states that this functionality isn't working and he needs a way to manually re-calculate things.