# Excel shows "#VALUE!" in cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Excel shows "#VALUE!" Until i select the cell, select the formula bar, then select a new cell. After that it will show the correct value. Is there a way to fix this in mass? I have >2000 cells I would like to fix, and doing it by hand is not worth the time.

Edit: I just fixed it by manually clicking the first set of calculations then copy and pasting it over the rest. But I would still appreciate any suggestions should this happen in the future.

Comment: You likely need to recalculate the entire worksheet, see https://superuser.com/questions/448376/what-is-the-excel-hotkey-to-re-calculate-all-formula-in-sheet

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, when I get more time I will edit my question to be more detailed on what I have already tried.

Thank you though

Comment: better share the Workbook over the cloud/Drop box to examine !