# Excel fill cell with "YES" if the date is after today (Windows 10, Excel 2010)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to use an IF function, to do something like "if date is after today, cell = YES, otherwise cell = blank".

I can't quite get my head around the double formula of pulling todays date within the IF function!

Could anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(A1>TODAY(),"YES","")
```

[image]

Comment: Although worth mentioning you might need to open the spreadsheet and/or [force a recalc](https://superuser.com/a/448390/1015063) to update those cells on a new day (in case you're reading the contents from powershell or something - not sure how it behaves when you open an excel sheet via powershell)