# Recalculate in Excel twice

Tags: microsoft-excel

For some reason, some of my cells in Excel don't update when the sheet is recalculated but they do update after a second recalculation. How could I make it so that when the sheet is recalculated, it does so twice?

Or, is there a way to simply recalculate that range of cells again?

Comment: My guess, and it can only be a guess as to the lack of information, is that your "formulas" are UDFs. And the UDFs have hard coded references.  If this is the case make the UDFs volatile.

Comment: What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: It means we need more information to be able to give a proper answer.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/448376/what-is-the-excel-hotkey-to-re-calculate-all-formula-in-sheet

Comment: ap0th0cary It's not. At all. I need a way to automatically make the worksheet recalculate twice at a time, or a way to fix my cells.

Comment: Also, I have no idea what else I should provide.

Answer (score 0):

Its not likely this, but there is a change. Check under File>Options>Formulas>Calculations options and make sure Automatic is selected.

[image]